# Swift, how to make a framework for both arm and i386

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I need to use a framework for and old obj-c project. The problem is, before I used to compile again and again code in a binary and then lipo it. Now with the swift architecture, it generate some Apple specific files, and of course, it is too hard for (or unintuitive to) Xcode to generate the framework for the architecture I want.
I googled how to do it, but to my surprise, I just found old post who talk about the old way with the standard binary output.

My question is how to simply generate a swift framework for the wanted arch. For the moment the only solution to my problem is to compile a framework for the simulator and another one for the phone. But I have no idea how to fat it. Or if it is the right approach.

I can't believe there is no way to ask Xcode to build it. But since we are talking about Xcode...

Comment: You should be able to do this by editing the build scheme with a script. How about this: [Creating a Universal iOS Framework in Xcode 7](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-universal-ios-framework-in-xcode-7)